# Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive even though I have specified the pattern

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am writing a function in haskell that checks if something is an element of a list or not.

I have the following code:

```
elementOf :: Eq a => a ->[a] -> Bool
elementOf _ [] = False
elememtOf x (y:ys) = (x==y) || elementOf x ys
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘elememtOf’: Patterns not matched: _ []
```

I do not understand why I am getting such error because I have a case for _ [].

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong please?

Thank You!

Comment: I recommend compiling with `-Wall` which would have notified you at compile time of nonexhaustive patterns as well as a function with no type signature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled the function name in the last pattern as `elememtOf` instead of `elementOf`.